# No ".cmake" file in home directory

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

I've been trying to compile a C++ project that links to the Caffe deep learning library. One piece of advice I received when using cmake was that the CMAKE_MODULES_PATH variable gets updated when I've compiled the library before so I can refer to Caffe in future cmake builds. This is supposed to be stored here:

```
~/.cmake/
```

However when I search for hidden items in my home directory, I can't find it anywhere. I'm running cmake 2.8 - is this a feature of another version or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake doesn't create any such directory. Nor does CMake search that location by default. You can create it yourself if you like, and add it to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.

Comment: CMake will create Package cache, see [cmake-packages](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry)